# Compass on 3d map Scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, opengl-es, scenekit

I want a compass like Google Earth. I'm using scenekit to create an earth with a camera that moves around it. The sphere is in a fixed position at (0,0,0). I move the camera using quaternions, applying the new orientation to the empty node. [scene scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEmPi.png)

I want to show the camera orientation relative to north pole in a compass like this
[compass Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qekjI.jpg)

I've tried calculating the angle with the up vector but I got wrong values.

```
let worldUp = earthOrbitalCamera.orbitalNode.worldUp
let angle = atan2(worldUp.y, worldUp.x)
```

With this angle I update the needle position. The issues is that I'm getting wrong values.

For example, the camera is align with pole north and the needle points to 40 degress to west.

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the spherical model is aligned so that its north-pole is always pointing +Y direction in the world space, the following code might work.

```
let worldUp = earthOrbitalCamera.orbitalNode.worldUp
let worldRight = earthOrbitalCamera.orbitalNode.worldRight

let angle = atan2(worldRight.y, worldUp.y)
```